# Creating xml Element with i:nil=false

Tags: xml-serialization

I am trying to create an Element which should be like this: "< Info i:nil="true" />

My Code is like that

from xlist in xmlReport

```
             select new XElement("Binding",
                    new XElement("ID", xlist.ID),
                    new XElement("Name", xlist.Name),


                    new XElement("Info"),
                    new XElement("Specification",
                    new XElement("Number", xlist.Number),
                    new XElement("SerialNumber", xlist.SerialNumber),
                    new XElement("Date", xlist.ConsumedDate),
                    new XElement("Site", xlist.Site)))
```

this line of code is generating XML mentioned above 
< Info/> tag

Instead of 
< Info i:nil=true/>

How do i get this "i:nil=true" ?

Comment: What is the "i" namespace meant to represent?

Answer (score 1):

Well this seems to do what you want, but you'll need to fill in the right namespace:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{    
    public static void Main()
    {
        XNamespace ns = "http://somenamespace";
        XElement element = new XElement("Root",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "i", ns.ToString()),
            new XElement("info",
                new XAttribute(ns + "nil", true)));

        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }    
}
```

The first attribute associates the prefix "i" with the namespace "http://somenamespace" for the root element and its descendants. The second attribute uses that namespace, and when the element is written out, the prefix is used to represent the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply .Thanks for your great help.